# Accessing Elasticache Redis from ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, amazon-elasticache

I have an application deployed in AWS EC2 which uses Elasticache Redis. I want to migrate it to ECS and I have everything set up, but when I run it the app gets timeout accessing Redis from ECS.

In the AWS documentation it says that Elasticache is ment to be accessed from EC2, but has anybody tried to use it from ECS?

Thanks in advance

PS: it's not a security groups problem because both AWS EC2 instances and ECS tasks use the same security group.

Comment: "can't access Redis" - it is not specific. What exactly is happening? Timeout, any error message? Example code samples?

Comment: I'm sorry, it gets timeout. Edited in the question

Comment: "PS: it's not a security groups problem because both AWS EC2 instances and ECS tasks use the same security group." Being in the same security group is meaningless. You still have to open ports in the security group to allow resources in the security group to talk to each other.

Comment: It's not meaningless, if you can access from EC2 with a security group, it means you must be able to access from ECS with the same security group. Its not Redis and ECS having the same security group, it's working EC2 instances and not working ECS

Comment: "if you can access from EC2 with a security group, it means you must be able to access from ECS with the same security group." Not quite. Is the ec2 instance and the ecs task in the same subnet?  Given it's an ECS task, does your dockerfile expose the correct port?

Comment: Yes they're in the same subnet. And no, exposing docker ports is only to make available ports for the docker container to be accessed from the outside world, this case is the opposite, I want to access elasticache redis (not docker) from ecs (docker)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. The issue was in a configuration file loaded by error, I was trying to connect to a redis located in another VPC instead of connecting to the one in the same VPC.

Answer (score 1):

I had encountered the similar timeout (reading from the comments) but that was because of TLS wasn't configured properly from my application. However, this shouldn't be the case if your application is working from the EC2 and being able to access the redis.

Some debugging questions that hit my head are:

- If you can access the redis connection locally through SSH tunneling or not?
- Is the ECS cluster and redis service lying in the same VPC and configured properly?
- Also how are you accessing redis from the EC2?

If you can let us know about these questions then probably we can help identify the root cause.